# Which ereaders support the EPUB3 format?

Tags: standard, epub

The EPUB3 format is the "next generation" for the widely-used EPUB format. (the differences between this and EPUB2 are described in [this question](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/59/what-are-the-differences-between-epub2-and-epub3)).

Which devices today support EPUB3? Where can I find out information about EPUB3 support?

Comment: This seems like a list question that, will not be accurate over time, and is generally discouraged on SE sites.

Comment: but an answer may always be improved later, or not?

Comment: There is precedent for canonical questions and answers per http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/ (last paragraph). See http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1986/what-are-the-canonical-answers-weve-discovered-over-the-years for examples.

Comment: @JamesJenkins I know what you mean, but as a community wiki question this will be of value to visitors to the site. The important thing to me was getting a link to the EPUB3 support grid into an answer.

Comment: I tend to concur, posted http://meta.ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/43/should-we-make-the-epub3-a-community-wiki-question

Answer (score 6):

Some supported EPUB3 Readers are

- [Helicon Books EPUB3 reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.heliconbooks.epub.epubreader&hl=en) (for Andriod)
- [Math jax](http://www.mathjax.org/resources/epub-readers/)
- [Online ePub3 reader](http://www.heliconbooks.com/article/onlinereader)
- [Gitden EPUB3 Book Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gitden.epub.reader.app&hl=en) (for Andriod and iOS)
- [Kobo Aura HD](http://www.kobo.com/koboaurahd) ([source](http://www.kobo.com/help/koboaurahd/response/?id=5486&type=3))

EPUB3 Support Websites

- [EPUB3 Overview](http://www.idpf.org/epub/30/spec/)
- [EPUB3 Support Grid](https://www.bisg.org/epub-3-support-grid)

Comment: Does Calibre support it?

Comment: @FlowRaja: This thread is about a year old, but according to the creator of calibre, there are no plans to support epub3: http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=183328

Comment: @FlowRaja Calibre supports epub3 very nice. Reads epub and edits them and changes metadata with a cute interface. Support most of the epub3 features.

Comment: The Mathjax link is broken but I found [this page](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/misc/epub.html) in their documentation.

Answer (score 4):

http://epubtest.org/ is very current and provides stats on overall eReader support as well as support for individual ePub 3 features. It would appear this site is updated regularly and is likely to continue to be current.

Answer (score 3):

There is no one reader that works across platforms. For a large and fully-loaded ePub3 ebook, the following readers will work pretty well. No reader is perfect, but these ones have minimal issues.

MacOS X:  iBooks, Adobe Digital Editions, Readium (in Chrome browser, but only with unzipped epub3 files)

iOS: iBooks, Adobe Digital Editions

Windows:  Adobe Digital Editions, Readium (in Chrome browser, but only with unzipped epub3 files), Azardi Reader

Android: Adobe Digital Editions

ChromeOS (on a Chromebook): Readium

I did try quite a few readers for this test. Need to do Linux, but maybe next week! Tested ePub3 book is about 900 pages, with video, slideshows, audio, images, etc.

BTW, treat the 'tests' of readers with a grain of salt. Gitden did very well on the tests, but cannot handle fixed layout files with embedded fonts, even the version updated to fix this issue. It also has a number of other issues, especially with large books.

Answer (score 0):

The [Infinity Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imeonsoft.infinity) on Android supports fully EPUB3 format. The app is distributed with a book, which has embedded youtube video.

You can use Readium extension on Google Chrome browser to read EPUB3 book on Windows or Mac. To use Readium app, open Chorme Web Store and search for Readium.